# Lambda expression to select all items where index > x

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lambda

I have a List which contains arrays of type `int`. Using a lambda expression how can I select a list of all items with an index bigger than 2?

For example the list below should return 8 and 9:

```
var items = new List<object>()
    {
        new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 },
        new int[1] { 4 },
        new int[5] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
    };

//var overTwoIndexItems = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Skip` to skip first three items in each array (i.e. items with indexes 0, 1 and 2). And you can use `SelectMany` to flatten results:

```
var overTwoIndexItems = items.SelectMany(a => ((int[])a).Skip(3));
```

Or more safe version (which will handle case when you are adding something that is not integer array to your list of objects):

```
var overTwoIndexItems = items.OfType<int[]>().SelectMany(a => a.Skip(3));
```

Result:

```
8, 9
```

BTW: Why are you using list of `object`? That looks like `ArrayList`. Main point of generics is strongly-typed arguments. Use `List<int[]>` instead. Then query will look like:

```
items.SelectMany(a => a.Skip(3))
```

Answer (score 2):

@Sergey had the correct method, but given it's an `IList<object>` you need to cast it first.

```
var result = items.Select (x => (int[])x).SelectMany (x => x.Skip(3));
//result = new int[]{ 8, 9 };
```